# InstallScript XP

Tags: installshield, installscript

I have an installscriptmsi project, whose output is setup.exe. I am able to install it on Vista and higher without any issues. I am not prompted for UAC. But on XP, I am prompted with Run As dialog always. I know it is because of setting LAAW_SHELLEXECUTEVERB = "runas" that I am getting the Run as prompt. But I do want my installer to run as admin on XP. I have also set RequiredExecutionLevel as Administrator under Release.

So is there a way I can get the installscriptmsi not to prompt for UAC on XP. I am using IS2012. I am pasting the script below.

```
function OnBegin()
STRING szProgram, szCmdLine, szDirectory;
NUMBER nShowWindow, nTimeOut, nOptions;
STRING szTestVersionKey;
begin
szProgram = "MsiExec.exe";
szDirectory = "";
nShowWindow = SW_NORMAL;
nTimeOut = 1000 * 60 * 10;
nOptions = LAAW_OPTION_USE_SHELLEXECUTE;
LAAW_SHELLEXECUTEVERB = "runas";

RegDBSetDefaultRoot( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE );

// uninstall  another 3rd party software if on the system.
szSofTestVersionKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\{15F6E1D5-12FF-4BBD-B02F-6440C7A2763C}";
if ( RegDBKeyExist(szTestVersionKey) ) then
    szCmdLine = "/uninstall {15F6B1B5-12FF-4DBD-A02F-6640C7A2863C} /norestart /quiet";
    LaunchApplication( szProgram, szCmdLine, szDirectory, nShowWindow, nTimeOut, nOptions ); 
  endif;

end;
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Windows XP does not have UAC.

Comment: @SLaks - I meant Run as dialog, as described at - http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/Subsystems/installshield19langref/helplibrary/LAAW_SHELLEXECUTEVERB.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing script already, so I would just condition whether you set `LAAW_SHELLEXECUTEVERB` to `runas`, or leave it as `open`. You might compare `SYSINFO.nOSMajor` to 6, or examine `SYSINFO.WINNT.bWinXP` to determine which OS you're on, and select the verb accordingly.